# Git Ignore a file inside a directory

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I have a file `googleservices.plist` inside  `ios/Runner/here`
I want to git to ignore the file.
I have added

```
ios/Runner/googleservices.plist
```

to the .gitignore file.
But it still doesnt ignore the file.

Comment: Did you add your .gitignore before or after staging?

Comment: If you stage the file and then attempt to ignore it, what is getting ignored is actually the further changes that you make to that file. The file still gets staged but new changes to the file won't. I guess that might be the case here.

Comment: if staged the file and committed it once.Now I want git to ignore the changes.But it isn't ignoring.

Comment: If you cached the file already than I you have  to untrack the file like here. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore

Comment: @TECH WITH KEVAL The solution that comes to my mind is to revert to the previous commit and stage files again with your new .gitignore. follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-do-i-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)